# Why does PSPice invert this AC current?

Tags: ac, simulation, pspice, phase, phase-shift

I'm running a simulation on a simple circuit in PSPice 9.1:
[image]
This voltage supply is set to provide a 1V AC signal with a frequency of 60 Hz. As the load is only resistive, the current should not have a phase shift.

Here are the results of the transient analysis:
[image]
In this plot, the green curve is voltage, and the red curve is current. These curves correspond with the markers placed in the schematic.

Why is the current 180 degrees out of phase with the voltage?

Comment: It's all relative. Loads dissipate +ve power, generators supply negative power, so the current orientation matters.

Comment: In PSpice, the currents that flow into the "device" are called positive. Conversely, currents that flow out of the "device" are called negative.  \

Comment: @G36 Thanks for your response. PSPice specifically calls this current "I(V1)". When I move the current marker to the negative terminal of the power supply, it is called "-I(V1)". Does this mean that psice defines current direction as going into the positive terminal?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Ah, negative power, I see. What a cool detail.

Comment: In a simulator, in real life actually, most things are obvious up to a polarity. I can never get them right. Just connect the thing and see which way it defines positive current. There are only two options, and you are guaranteed by Murphy's Law to pick the wrong one.

Comment: @Neil_UK Change only the shape of the device ... adding a "+" at the right point ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSpice is using the *passive current convention*.

That means that all branch currents are considered positive when they flow in to the positive terminal.

With this convention, devices that absorb power (like resistors) will have \$I\times V>0\$ and devices that provide power (like voltage sources with passive loads) will have \$I\times V<0\$.